# When to use action hooks and plugins

Tags: plugins, database, ajax, hooks

I have a page which I want user to be able to post info which I then upload into a database. I am doing my requests via ajax and I am trying to establish my database connection and sql querying via an action hook. First off is this a good pratice?

My code (the relative part):

HTML:

```
<div id="user_info">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Fullständigt namn" required autocomplete="off"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" required autocomplete="off"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="address" placeholder="Adress" required autocomplete="off"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="co_address" placeholder="C/O Adress"  autocomplete="off"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="city" placeholder="Namn" required autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function updateDB(name, email, address, co_address, city){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'det_lilla_extra',
            name: name,
            email: email,
            address: address,
            co_address: co_address,
            city: city
        },
    });
```

PHP (action hook):

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_det_lilla_extra', 'det_lilla_extra');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_det_lilla_extra', 'det_lilla_extra' );
function det_lilla_extra(){
    global $wpdb;
    //var_dump($_POST);
    $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (name, email, address, co_address, city) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
    $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['co_address'], $_POST['city']));
    wp_die();
}
```

I've been able to get this far by following and looking at others. But my problem now is that for my action hook to work I need to create a plugin. I dont know how to do this, I've been googling to find turorials but I dont really know what to look for, so its kinda hard to pinpoint what to do.

So my questions:

1. Is this "good" pratice what i have done? Could I do it another way (regarding having an action hook for database connection)
2. Is a plugin what i need here? And if so, how do i go about creating it?

ALSO: Currently my action hook does not work since I have not enabled the plugin (i think this is the reason). But everything else should work though.

Comment: A plugin is a PHP file with a comment at the top, literally take your code and put `/* Plugin Name: Vonhacts plugin */` at the top then place the file in the plugins folder, there's no special voodoo needed. Also there's no reason this wouldn't work in `functions.php`, but you shouldn't be creating tables, and updating them in a theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, see this WordPress Codex page: [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

You don't technically need to write a plugin to do what you want to do, but it is good practise to do so, especially for the kind of functionality you are building. (Building a database table, handling form data, submitting with AJAX, etc.) Check out [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) for a lot more info on that.

That being said, here's the main issues I see with your code right now.

### Security risks

Right now, you're assuming that user-submitted data is always correct. This has an extremely high security risk. You should **always** assume that users will try to input incorrect data. To make your code more secure, you should first validate your data before inserting it into the database.

Here is a quick example of validating the data for the `$_POST['name']` field, and sending a json error if the data is "invalid".

```
if ( !isset($_POST['name'] || strlen($_POST['name']) > 30 ) {
    // Check if 'name' is set, and the length is shorter than 30
    wp_send_json_error( 'Error: Your name should be no longer than 30 characters' );
}
```

### Inserting data

While you are doing good using `$wpdb->prepare` for a raw SQL query, you don't actually need it for the `$wpdb->insert` function. See the [Class Reference/wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row) for an example of how to use `$wpdb->insert`.

I've also used the correct way to use `insert` in the example below.

### Putting it all together

First, we want to enqueue our Javascript so that WordPress can use it. We are also passing our `ajaxurl` (admin-ajax.php) through here for easy use in our Javascript.

```
function your_submit_order_scripts) {
    // Register your Javascript file
    wp_register_script( 'your-submit-order', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/your-submit-order.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

    // Send ajaxurl as variable to this script
    $local_arr = array(
        'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'your-submit-order', 'yourSubmitOrder', $local_arr );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your-submit-order' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_submit_order_scripts' );
```

Next we add our callback, this will process the data that we post with AJAX. The add_action part makes sure that our AJAX post function knows where to send the data to.

```
// Use this callback function for logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_det_lilla_extra', 'det_lilla_extra');

// Also allow this function to be used by non-logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_det_lilla_extra', 'det_lilla_extra' );

function det_lilla_extra(){

    // Convert form data to array
    $formdata = array();
    parse_str($_POST['formdata'], $formdata);

    // Check if name field is valid
    if ( !isset($formdata['name'] || strlen($formdata['name']) > 30 ) {
        // Check if 'name' is set, and the length is shorter than 30
        wp_send_json_error( 'Error: Your name should be no longer than 30 characters' );
    }

    // More validation goes here depending on your needs...
    // For example, is the email address a real email?
    // Is the address written in the correct format?
    // Is the city a real city?

    // If validation has no errors, insert data
    if ( $wpdb->insert( 
            'orders', 
            array( 
                'name' => $_POST['name'], 
                'email' => $_POST['email',
                // etc.
            ), 
            array( 
                '%s', 
                '%s',
                // etc.
            ) 
        ) 
    ) {
        // If $wpdb->insert was successful, send success message back to AJAX updateDB function
        wp_send_json_success(array('message' => 'Successfully uploaded!');

    } else {
        // If insert was unsuccessfull, send error message back to AJAX
        wp_send_json_error('Error: Something went wrong');
    }

    // Don't technically need it when using wp_send_json
    wp_die();
}
```

Finally, we make our Javascript. I have updated your updateDB function to work in a similar way to the examples posted on the WordPress Codex page linked above.

Also, since you are using a HTML form to enter data, we can make use of the jQuery `serialize()` function to make things easier.

```
function updateDB() {
    // Create the data to send with AJAX
    var data = {
        'action': 'det_lilla_extra',
        'formdata': $('form').serialize() // Convert entire form to data
    };

    // Note how we use yourSubmitOrder.ajaxurl to pass the url to admin-ajax.php
    // We set this our your_submit_order_scripts function earlier
    jQuery.post(yourSubmitOrder.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        if ( reponse.success == true ) {
            alert(response.data.message);
        } else {
            alert(response.data);
        }
    });
}
```

I probably spent way too much time writing up this answer, but hopefully it's useful to you. I've spent a lot of time figuring out the best way to use AJAX in WordPress, so I see this as giving back to every person and resource that has taught me!

If anything is unclear then feel free to comment.

Comment: I forgot to add the formdata conversion, so I added that now! You can see at the top of the callback function. Good luck!